# uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut returns less value of token B than present in reverses when provide full amounts of token A

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, hardhat, uniswap, uniswapv2

I have the next code to get familiar with uniswap mechanics:

- create pair contract
- get reserves
- invoke `getAmountsOut` and provide all UNI token reserves

```
  const pairAddress = await _V2Factory.getPair(uniToken, wethToken);
  const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(
    pairAddress,
    IUniswapV2Pair.abi,
    _provider
  );
  const tmpReserves = await pairContract.getReserves();
  const reserves = [reserves.reserve0, reserves.reserve1];
  console.log("reserves", reserves);

  const output = await router.getAmountsOut(reserves[0], [
    uniToken.address,
    wethToken.address,
  ]);
  console.log("output", output);
```

Output is:

- reserves: `[ 36851089197799104779745113323n, 281312509765248795074n ]`
- output: `[ 36851089197799104779745113323n, 140444953548298972803n ]`

The question is why I do not receive as the second element of `output` array equals to `281312509765248795074n` - the full `WETH` liquidity in pair but just part of liquidity equals to `140444953548298972803n` value?

I'm running local hardhat node and 3-rd parties actions should not affect the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how math works.

Let's call the reserves values `x` and `y`. In your example

```
x = 36851089197799104779745113323n
y = 281312509765248795074n
```

Before and after the swap, the value of their product needs to remain constant `x * y = k`. You are swapping `x` UNI, increasing the reserve to `2x`, so the WETH reserve needs to go to `y/2`:

```sh
2x * y/2 = x * y
```

That means your output is `y/2`, which checks out with the number you found, minus approximations due to the swap fee.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a misunderstanding of how the `getAmountsOut()` function works in **Uniswap**.

Let's break down the code and clarify the behavior:

1. `getReserves()` -> retrieves the current reserves of tokens in the pair. In your case, you're fetching the reserves of `UNI` and `WETH` tokens.
2. `getAmountsOut()` -> calculates the expected output amount(s) for a given input amount. In your code, you're providing the reserves of `UNI` tokens as the input amount and specifying that you want to convert them to `WETH`.

Now, looking at the output that you're getting for `getAmountsOut()`, i.e.:

```js
output: [ 36851089197799104779745113323n, 140444953548298972803n ]
```

- The first element of the output array matches the input amount of `UNI` tokens. This makes sense as you're converting `UNI` tokens to `WETH`, so the amount of `UNI` tokens remains the same.
- The second element of the output array represents the calculated output amount of `WETH` tokens. However, this doesn't necessarily match the total liquidity of `WETH` in the pair. Instead, it represents the expected amount of `WETH` tokens you would receive when swapping the input amount of `UNI` tokens, based on the current reserves and the swapping mechanism of **Uniswap**.

So, the discrepancy you're observing is not due to any external factors or third-party actions, but rather it's inherent in how **Uniswap** calculates output amounts based on input amounts and current reserves. The output amount will depend on factors such as *slippage*, *liquidity depth*, and the *ratio of reserves* between the two tokens in the pair.